# Elecrtrum Change Address Problem

Tags: address, electrum, change

While I sending BTC to specific adress, it went to it but also it went to another address. How can i refund it?

Comment: You need to be more specific.

Comment: I was trying to send 2 mBTC to a specific address. This address received only a little part of it and majority of this BTC has sent went to another change address - as i understand created by electrum itself-. Also i get that this is how electrum works and these change addresses are mine.
But how can i get this btc back from this new address? All of their balance shown as "0".

Comment: The new address is your own, you don't need to do anything. Your balance is probably 0 because Electrum doesn't spend unconfirmed outputs - so just wait until your transaction confirms.

Comment: How long i need to wait for confirmation? 8 hours has past from the sending, balance is still 0.

Comment: My transaction has done. Point is not that. I think it is about change addresses. 
But on addresses tab all addresses have 0 balance. Only one of them have differen value than 0. A tx tab has shown as 2.
What does it mean? What should i do? Am i allowed to use btc from this adress?

Comment: So transaction has confirmed but your balance is still 0?

Comment: Absouletely that.